# What are the exact steps to deploy application on Windows Phone

Tags: codenameone

- How to deploy Windows UWP application on Windows 8 Device. Please provide exact steps
- When tried to deploy with Windows application deploy tool. Its searching for XAP file, but the current build creates zip file, so not sure how to deploy it

-Also on building Windows build I am getting below error

```
Executing: c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java -Dretrolambda.inputDir=C:\Users\Shai\AppData\Local\Temp\build7214845896341024238xxx\classes -Dretrolambda.classpath=C:\Users\Shai\AppData\Local\Temp\build7214845896341024238xxx\classes;C:\Users\Shai\AppData\Local\Temp\temp9143287062799870765.jar -Dretrolambda.outputDir=C:\Users\Shai\AppData\Local\Temp\build7214845896341024238xxx\classes_retrolamda -Dretrolambda.bytecodeVersion=49 -Dretrolambda.defaultMethods=true -jar C:\Users\Shai\AppData\Local\Temp\temp554571844756730289.jar Retrolambda 2.0.3

Bytecode version: 49 (Java 5)

Default methods:  true

Input directory:  C:\Users\Shai\AppData\Local\Temp\build7214845896341024238xxx\classes

Output directory: C:\Users\Shai\AppData\Local\Temp\build7214845896341024238xxx\classes_retrolamda

Classpath:        C:\Users\Shai\AppData\Local\Temp\build7214845896341024238xxx\classes;C:\Users\Shai\AppData\Local\Temp\temp9143287062799870765.jar

Saving lambda class: com/iz/service/APIHandler$$Lambda$1

Saving lambda class: com/iz/service/APIHandler$$Lambda$3

Saving lambda class: com/iz/service/APIHandler$$Lambda$4

Saving lambda class: com/iz/service/APIHandler$$Lambda$5

Saving lambda class: com/iz/service/APIHandler$$Lambda$6

Saving lambda class: com/iz/service/APIHandler$$Lambda$7

Saving lambda class: com/iz/service/APIHandler$$Lambda$8

Saving lambda class: com/iz/service/APIHandler$$Lambda$9

Executing: java -Xmx1024m -jar win_xmlvm.jar --in=C:\Users\Shai\AppData\Local\Temp\build7214845896341024238xxx\classes_retrolamda --resource=C:\Users\Shai\AppData\Local\Temp\build7214845896341024238xxx\ZMT\ZMT\res/ --out=C:\Users\Shai\AppData\Local\Temp\build7214845896341024238xxx\ZMT\ZMT\src --target=csharp --app-name=ZMT Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)

               at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.run(Boot.java:306)

               at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.main(Boot.java:159)

Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: expected type int but found int

               at com.android.dx.cf.code.BaseMachine.popArgs(BaseMachine.java:198)

               at com.android.dx.cf.code.Simulator$SimVisitor.visitNoArgs(Simulator.java:331)

               at com.android.dx.cf.code.BytecodeArray.parseInstruction(BytecodeArray.java:541)

               at com.android.dx.cf.code.Simulator.simulate(Simulator.java:99)

               at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.processBlock(Ropper.java:678)

               at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.doit(Ropper.java:633)

               at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.convert(Ropper.java:250)

               at org.xmlvm.proc.out.DEXmlvmOutputProcess.processMethod(DEXmlvmOutputProcess.java:958)

               at org.xmlvm.proc.out.DEXmlvmOutputProcess.process(DEXmlvmOutputProcess.java:673)

               at org.xmlvm.proc.out.DEXmlvmOutputProcess.generateDEXmlvmFile(DEXmlvmOutputProcess.java:423)

               at org.xmlvm.proc.out.DEXmlvmOutputProcess.generateDEXmlvmFile(DEXmlvmOutputProcess.java:373)

               at org.xmlvm.proc.out.DEXmlvmOutputProcess.processPhase1(DEXmlvmOutputProcess.java:345)

               at org.xmlvm.proc.XmlvmProcessImpl.forwardOrProcessPhase1(XmlvmProcessImpl.java:209)

               at org.xmlvm.proc.XmlvmProcessImpl.forwardOrProcessPhase1(XmlvmProcessImpl.java:206)

               at org.xmlvm.proc.XmlvmProcessImpl.forwardOrProcessPhase1(XmlvmProcessImpl.java:206)

               at org.xmlvm.proc.XmlvmProcessImpl.forwardOrProcessPhase1(XmlvmProcessImpl.java:206)

               at org.xmlvm.proc.XmlvmProcessor.process(XmlvmProcessor.java:157)

               at org.xmlvm.proc.XmlvmProcessor.process(XmlvmProcessor.java:137)

               at org.xmlvm.Main.main(Main.java:53)

               ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is the old XMLVM pipeline for Windows 8.x builds. It was always flaky especially with multi-dimensional arrays e.g. if you have code like `int[][][]` or even `int[][]` that might not work properly in that old pipeline.

We thought about maintaining support for that but since Microsoft is pushing Windows 10 upgrades even for low end Lumias and decided to discontinue Skype for Windows Phone we assume the old 8.x target is dead.

For full instructions on deploying and building with UWP check out the [developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/appendix-uwp.html).

Older targets such as Windows 8.x/7.x desktops/tablets can be served by our desktop/JavaScript build targets so targeting a dead platform is probably not the best usage of our resources.

Comment: Please give me deployment steps of widows 8 device

Comment: They are in the UWP developer guide section